# In Dracula Untold why was the vampire bound to the cave? Why would Vlad free him by drinking blood?

Tags: dracula, dracula-untold

Why was the vampire bound to the cave?  How come drinking blood would free him?

> Why wasn't Vlad bound to a cave after drinking human blood? Were there other responsibilities associated with becoming a permanent vampire?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't been able to find a copy of the script for Dracula: Untold, probably because it's still so new. Both questions, though, were answered in the scene where Vlad seeks out the elder vampire.

> The elder vampire (a noble who was cursed into the first vampire after summoning a demon) explained that there were two parts to his curse. The first was that he was transformed into the monster that Vlad sees, forced to live off human blood. The second part of the curse was that he could not leave the confines of the cave, and would be trapped there for all eternity UNLESS a righteous man volunteered to take his burden.

The second part is where Vlad comes in, and it also explains (somewhat) the "3-day waiting period" seen for the powers. As we saw,

> the elder still couldn't leave the cave even after Vlad accepted the deal and willfully drank the blood. It wasn't until the moment that Vlad willfully ACCEPTED the curse itself - without any hope of a cure - that the elder could finally leave the cave.

As for WHY the nature of the curse, and why human blood?

> The demon probably chose human blood because it's one of the few substances that most people would rather die than consume. As for the loophole, the demon most likely doubted that any righteous man would ever knowingly accept such a curse, and therefore thought that he was really trapping the noble in a cave for all time.

The movie overall does contain some whopping plot holes, but I thought this part was actually well done. Charles Dance absolutely stole every scene he was in, especially this one.